# How to put data into clipboard on a Windows Mobile device written in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile

I want to put some data in the clipboard using c# and the Compact Framework. I am using a Windows Mobile device.

How to put data into clipboard on a Windows Mobile device written in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a using System.Windows.Forms;

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject()
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the clipbard belongs to the user, so you should never put data into the clipboard unless the user asks you to. (by choosing cut/copy etc).

.NET has a [Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.aspx) object that you can use to put data in the clipboard.

the clipboard object has several static methods that you can use to `SetText`, `SetImage`, `SetAudio` or `SetDataObject`

> Note: An object must be serializable for it to be put on the Clipboard. If you pass a non-serializable object to a Clipboard method, the method will fail without throwing an exception.